# Como vincular uma pergunta com uma resposta do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando criar um sistema de perguntas e respostas em PHP e MySQL.

Já tenho o banco criado, gostaria de saber como fazer com que a pergunta esteja vinculada a resposta que o aluno fez.
E mostrar em um loop todas as respostas respondidas por cada aluno.

```
tblperguntas id_pergunta titulo pergunta
tblrespostas id_resposta resposta
```

Comment: Você tem que ter mais uma tabela, onde guardará o id do aluno e o id da resposta.

Comment: defina melhor a estrutura do banco de dados, do jeito que ele está, se possível coloque algumas imagens das tabelas e relações do seu banco

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Esqueci de mencionar que existe uma tabela de usuários existente,para trazer o id do id_aluno e  id_resposta seria por inner ou chave estrangeira?

Comment: Teria que ser uma chave estrangeira, isso é necessário porque cada resposta pode ser escolhida por um ou mais alunos, então é uma relação `1-N`, toda relação que houver um `N` é necessário criar uma tabela 'auxiliar'.